# insert json into table jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is probably really simple but I can't get it to work to save my life.

I get following json from external api. Now I tried to create one loop for country (it is my key) and second for id, name, last_name, profession and gender.

```
{
        "Argentina": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Silvia",
                "last_name": "Msao",
                "profession": "actor",
                "gender": "Female"
            }
        ],
        "France": [
            {
                "id": 148,
                "name": "Pauline",
                "last_name": "Huwam",
                "profession": "manager",
                "gender": "Female"
            },
            {
                "id": 149,
                "name": "Pierre-Jean",
                "last_name": "La Manche",
                "profession": "actor",
                "gender": "Male"
            }

        ]
    }
```

Now I have to parse into  html table using jquery libraries.

My java script code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         tables = '<table id="country">\n' +
            '\n' +
            '      <tr>\n' +
            '        <th colspan="5">Country</th>\n' +
            '      </tr>\n' +
            '      <tr>\n' +
            '        <td>Id</td>\n' +
            '        <td>Name</td>\n' +
            '        <td>Last name</td>\n' +
            '        <td>Additional info</td>\n' +
            '        <td>Gender</td>\n' +
            '      </tr>\n' +


            //internal loop
            '      <tr>\n' +
            '        <td>1</td>\n' +
            '        <td>kk</td>\n' +
            '        <td>www</td>\n' +
            '        <td>sdadainfo</td>\n' +
            '        <td>Male</td>\n' +
            '      </tr>\n' +


            '    </table>';

        $( document ).ready(function() {


            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:8090/di-rest-svc/v1/aggregateddata/ctry/',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    //TODO
                    //how to read country from data

                    $.each(data, function (index, countryPerson) {
                        console.log(countryPerson[0]);
                        console.log("dupa");
                        tables = tables + '<table id="country">\n' +
                            '\n' +
                            '      <tr>\n' +
                            '        <th colspan="5">Country</th>\n' +
                            '      </tr>\n' +
                            '      <tr>\n' +
                            '        <td>Id</td>\n' +
                            '        <td>Name</td>\n' +
                            '        <td>Last name</td>\n' +
                            '        <td>Additional info</td>\n' +
                            '        <td>Gender</td>\n' +
                            '      </tr>\n';


                        /*var mytable = $('<table></table>').attr({ id: "basicTable" });
                        var rows = new Number($("#rowcount").val());
                        var cols = new Number($("#columncount").val());
                        var tr = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                            var row = $('<tr></tr>').attr({ class: ["class1", "class2", "class3"].join(' ') }).appendTo(mytable);
                            for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                                $('<td></td>').text("text1").appendTo(row);
                            }

                        }*/
                        /* console.log("TTTTT:"+mytable.html());
                         mytable.appendTo("#box");*/

                        $.each(countryPerson, function (index1, person) {
                            tables = tables + '<tr>\n' +
                                '        <td>person.id</td>\n' +
                                '        <td>person.name</td>\n' +
                                '        <td>person.last_name</td>\n' +
                                '        <td>person.additonal_info</td>\n' +
                                '        <td>person.gender</td>\n' +
                                '      </tr>\n';


                            // console.log(person.name);
                            //  console.log(person.last_name);
                            // console.log(person.additonal_info);
                            // console.log(person.gender);

                        });
                        tables = tables + '</table>';

                    });
                }
            });


            // alert(response);
            //document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = response1.id;
            //document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = response1.name;
            //document.getElementById("lastName").innerHTML = response1.lastName;
            //document.getElementById("additionalInfo").innerHTML = response1.additionalInfo;
            //document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = response1.country;
            //document.getElementById("gender").innerHTML = response1.gender;

            alert(tables);
            $(tables).appendTo('#tables');

            //$('<table><tr><td>xyz</td></tr></table>').appendTo( '#tables' );
            //$('<table><tr><td>ccc</td></tr></table>').appendTo( '#tables' );
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

        <div id="tables"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please fix your code snippet.

Comment: You don't say what's going wrong, but here's one possibility - you're calling the anonymous success function with an argument of `data` but then you're calling `$.each` on a variable called `result`.  `success: function (data) {

                    $.each(result, function(key, value){`

Comment: `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` fix that, please.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't actually give us a detailed problem statement, but the issue appears to be that you're printing literal strings into your table instead of inserting the values of variables. Anything within a quote mark in JavaScript is taken literally as a string and displayed as-is. You need to end your strings, use the variable name and then restart the string again:

```js
var data = {
  "Argentina": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Silvia",
    "last_name": "Msao",
    "profession": "actor",
    "gender": "Female"
  }],
  "France": [{
      "id": 148,
      "name": "Pauline",
      "last_name": "Huwam",
      "profession": "manager",
      "gender": "Female"
    },
    {
      "id": 149,
      "name": "Pierre-Jean",
      "last_name": "La Manche",
      "profession": "actor",
      "gender": "Male"
    }

  ]
};

var tables = "";

$.each(data, function(index, countryPerson) {
  //console.log(countryPerson[0]);
  //console.log("dupa");
  tables = tables + '<table id="country">' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<th colspan="5">' + index + '</th>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Id</td>' +
    '<td>Name</td>' +
    '<td>Last name</td>' +
    '<td>Additional info</td>' +
    '<td>Gender</td>' +
    '</tr>';

  $.each(countryPerson, function(index1, person) {
    tables = tables + '<tr>' +
      '<td>' + person.id + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + person.name + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + person.last_name + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + (person.additional_info ? person.additional_info : "") + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + person.gender + '</td>' +
      '</tr>';
  });
  tables = tables + '</table>';
});

$(tables).appendTo('#tables');
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  border: solid 1px #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tables"></div>
```